# Peerfinder returns non-existing peers in WP8

Tags: bluetooth, windows-phone-8, proximity

I am using [PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.networking.proximity.peerfinder.findallpeersasync.aspx) in my WP8 application to discover devices running the same application by the Bluetooth interface.

The function has to return the list of peers which are in range. However, it also returns the devices which have recently become peered with the application but are not in range anymore. Even by uninstalling and installing the application, those old devices are returned by FindAllPeersAsync() function.

Is there any way to prevent this thing to happen?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that FindAllPeersAsync() method always returns the devices which were paired before. I solved this by removing paired devices in Bluetooth settings.

But as good solution, your app should do something like "online" request to determine if peer is really present in your range.